# Jupyterhub Bitnami pod evicted

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-kubernetes-engine, jupyter-lab, bitnami, jupyterhub

I have installed helm chart for jupyterhub bitnami over GKE.

When a singleuser pod is created, it gets "evicted" after some time because of ephermal storage with following error

"Pod ephemeral local storage usage exceeds the total limit 1Gi"

I did not find in documentation how to increase ephermal storage. Can you please tell how can I increase this ephermal storage or what is the alternative way to fix this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

After scratching my head for hours, I had to study the implementation of  `jupyter kubernetes spawner` [here](https://github.com/jupyterhub/kubespawner/blob/main/kubespawner/spawner.py#L1405) and also `kubernetes` client library [here](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/client/models/v1_resource_requirements.py). I've found the way to set `ephermal-storage` for `jupyterhub` user notebook. Unfortunately, there was not documentation for it.

I added `extraResources` in `hub.configuration` within `values.yaml`

```
extraResource:
  limits: 
    ephemeral-storage: '5Gi'
  guarantees:
    ephemeral-storage: '5Gi'
```